# Returning Multiple Columns under a single Then Clause using Case in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a piece of case statement which I wish to execute but the output is showing Missing Keyword.
Please assist me in getting the correct output.

```
CASE WHEN TRIM(STG.CLIENTCOUNTRY) in (select CPC_COUNTRY_CODE from ABC_DEVELOPER.EN_COUNTRY where COUNTRY_CODE='US')
        THEN
        (
    DECODE(COALESCE(scl.abc_do_not_solict_telemarktg_fl,scl.ov_do_not_solicit_telemktg_fla,scl.vigo_do_not_solicit_telemktg_f),'Y',DECODE(sbs.optout_flag,'N','Y',NULL),NULL) opt_in_phone_flag,
            DECODE(COALESCE(scl.abc_do_not_solict_telemarktg_fl,scl.ov_do_not_solicit_telemktg_fla,scl.vigo_do_not_solicit_telemktg_f),'Y',DECODE(sbs.optout_flag,'N',sbs.add_date,NULL),NULL) opt_in_phone_date,
            'Y' opt_out_sms_flag,
            sbs.add_date opt_out_sms_date,
            NULL opt_in_sms_flag,
            NULL opt_in_sms_date,
            DECODE(COALESCE(scl.abc_do_not_share,scl.ov_do_not_share,scl.vigo_do_not_share),'Y',DECODE(sbs.do_not_share,'Y','Y',NULL),NULL) opt_out_share_flag,
            DECODE(COALESCE(scl.abc_do_not_share,scl.ov_do_not_share,scl.vigo_do_not_share),'Y',DECODE(sbs.do_not_share,'Y',sbs.add_date,NULL),NULL) opt_out_share_date,

)
Else
(
   Existing Code
)
```

There is an end case statement. But there is certain error with these part of the code. I was wondering more on the lines of multiple statements under a single then clause.

Comment: I don't think there should be a '{' after `THEN`

Also, does not seem to be the entire query

Comment: Is this part of a query (then it isn't PL/SQL but "just" SQL) or part of a stored procedure (then it _would_ be PL/SQL)

Comment: Nesting DECODE IN DECODE is really hard to read\

Comment: Yeah the '{' shouldn't be there. I rectified it. But still it is showing me right parenthesis missing.

Comment: There is an end case statement. But there is certain error with these part of the code. I was wondering more on the lines of multiple statements under a single then clause.

Comment: can you post the existing code to get a specific answer to your question ???

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` is a function that can be used to define the value of a single row/column. You can't use it to add or remove columns from your resultset. That's just not how SQL works.

To make this work, you'll need to repeat the `CASE` logic for each column that needs to implement it. The columns will have to exist whether or not you intend to use them. In the situations where you expect to ignore these columns, the best solution is simply to leave them `null`.

Answer (score 0):

"END " statement is missing 
Please check the official document

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

Example

```
SELECT cust_last_name,
   CASE credit_limit WHEN 100 THEN 'Low'
   WHEN 5000 THEN 'High'
   ELSE 'Medium' END
   FROM customers;
```

New edit

```
CASE 

WHEN TRIM(STG.CLIENTCOUNTRY) 
IN (SELECT CPC_COUNTRY_CODE FROM ABC_DEVELOPER.EN_COUNTRY WHERE COUNTRY_CODE='US')
THEN DECODE(COALESCE(scl.abc_do_not_solict_telemarktg_fl,scl.ov_do_not_solicit_telemktg_fla,scl.vigo_do_not_solicit_telemktg_f),'Y',DECODE(sbs.optout_flag,'N','Y',NULL),NULL)
ELSE 'existing code' opt_in_phone_flag,

WHEN TRIM(STG.CLIENTCOUNTRY) 
IN (SELECT CPC_COUNTRY_CODE FROM ABC_DEVELOPER.EN_COUNTRY WHERE COUNTRY_CODE='US')
THEN DECODE(COALESCE(scl.abc_do_not_solict_telemarktg_fl,scl.ov_do_not_solicit_telemktg_fla,scl.vigo_do_not_solicit_telemktg_f),'Y',DECODE(sbs.optout_flag,'N',sbs.add_date,NULL),NULL) 
ELSE 'existing code' opt_in_phone_date,
.
.
.
END
```

Comment: Yeah, I got your point - but my query is somewhere else. There seems to be an error while using multiple statements under then clause.

Comment: Seems like you are returning multiple results/columns inside "then" (opt_in_phone_flag, opt_in_phone_date...etc) which is not possible.... you will have to return single result/column within "then" OR you will have to use multiple "When" to return multiple columns.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Could you please elaborate on reutrning multiple columns   under a single then clause? like how should i insert the when clause in each of the statements

Comment: What do you want to return when country code not in table ABC_DEVELOPER.EN_COUNTRY table ?

Comment: The query will not process anymore ie. it won't populate a table. The countrycode has to be US. Anyway, but could you explain how to return/populate multiple columns inside a single then statement, or else a different approach to the question alltogether?

Comment: I want to populate multiple columns when countrycode is US

Comment: Thanks Rakesh for your input.